# How load PHP website on the iPad simulator or device?

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, ipad, apache

I have one `.php` web site and I want to put it in iPad application "web application".

I mean create `UIWebView` and load files in `WebView`, so my First question is, is it possible to create this `webApp` and can I run it on Xcode simulator?

What do I need for implementing this application (Apache, MySQL) inside ipad outside?

Basically I want to have all my `.php` class inside of app and run it via iPad app, it means that if I hadn't any internet I can run the application.

Since I want to run it in both iPad and XCode simulator.

Would you please give me some hints for implement this application?

Comment: its not very mature yet, but if you're doing testing of a site in ipad like environment you can try freesponsive.com

Comment: I don't know what you want to make but since you used the term webapp, I'm going to assume all you want is an iPad app but coded using web languages, to do that you can just simply create a website put it online and people can access it via safari, they can then add it to their homescreen and you have a webapp that can run like a normal application. Here's the apple documentation: [Apple Dev Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/configuringwebapplications/configuringwebapplications.html)

Comment: ^^ a good example would be Grooveshark's HTML5 webapp.

Comment: @Lenny thanks but I want load php inside app since I also want to have offline application

Comment: @ghazal - I just don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points you need to think about:

- **App Store Approval** - if you intend to market this app (i.e it's not for jailbroken devices via Cydia, or an in-house corporate app) then you will most likely run in to issues with the approval process.*

  1. You're intending to bundle in a scripting language with your application. Now this may not be an issue depending on whether or not this is exposed to the end-user; but you do run the risk of Apple finding out and pulling the plug.
  2. The alternative to bundling in a scripting language (PHP in your case) is going to be loading the code off of an external server. This is a no-no straight away, as Apple requires your application to have functionality offline - or atleast they did. Where this leaves all the Social Networking and other network-dependant apps... Well, I guess there are exceptions!
- **Device Performance** - you're essentially intending to run a small web server on a mobile device; a tablet in this case. This could be very resource intensive, so is probably not wise. I personally wouldn't want my battery being drained because someone has decided that they want to bundle in a web server with their application.

Your implementation idea itself is sound, in the respect of using a UIWebView. You should probably check out the Apache Cordova/PhoneGap framework, and that should satisfy your needs and provide an off-the-shelf way of packaging up your web app. If you do need custom functionality then it's worth looking at anyway; plugins are relatively easy to develop, there's a wide range available already and the plans for cordova now are to allow developers to implement it into native applications. (Say, if only one view requires PhoneGap functionality etc)

Personally, I fail to see what requires PHP that can not be done via HTML5 and PhoneGap. There are storage options available, SQL options, you're using web technologies so can easily query external web services. It's also a lot safer with regards to app approval - as it's tried and tested; *there are many applications build using such solutions already in the store*.

I think you need a serious re-think. Otherwise, perhaps you could post some more details?

Comment: thank you so much for your detail information, so if I use PhoneGap I can create this staff for iPad,isn't it? one more question if I have my application via phoneGap and then export it for ipad can I run flash on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that PHP is a server-side language. So do you want to run a server on your iPad? If so, you can develop PHP applications on a proper desktop/laptop and then view them on iPad Safari browser over Wifi.

Otherwise you can install [LightHTTPd server with PHP](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=22926) libraries, [MySQL](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=58410), CURL and all from [Cydia app store](https://cydia.saurik.com/) on a jailbroken iOS device to get a full environment. For Android there is this app [PAW server](http://paw-android.fun2code.de/) available which can run an Apache server in such devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check your website is working fine on small devices, or you want to check responsiveness of your website. Go to:[Ipad Peek](http://ipadpeek.com/) and run your website on given devices/simulators using url.

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search pulled up this free framework: http://www.ipfaces.org/

I've never used to before, but it might do what you need.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.